# Why commits orders are different from GitHub API and webpage?

Tags: github-api, git-commit

I am conducting commit history analysis experiment, and the goal is by searching the existence of certain files/dirs in each commit (by using binary search algorithm) to find a special commit that refactors a repo from normal to a monorepo.

The problem is that the commits order I retrieved from GitHub API is different from what I saw on webpages, taking the repository `mui/material-ui` as an example:

- from [this API link](https://api.github.com/repos/mui/material-ui/commits?page=475), we could know that the previous commit right BEFORE `8659c6991adb9e2f83a8f3af6bd90321adfe8f68` is `f2ed40aac85f8e69bb44e4f21c12ced40d1b11a5`;
- however, from [this commits webpage](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/commits/8659c6991adb9e2f83a8f3af6bd90321adfe8f68) the previous commit is `dedcf74`, which is different from what from API.

This order difference makes my analysis algorithm produce wrong results, given the commit history inputs to it seems like not correct.

I am starting noticing that in API page, a commit's `parents` field may contain a different sha than the commit right before the investigated one (in this case, happens to be `dedcf74`), but I am not familiar with how that field works and why it is an array, or even whether the problem does have something to do with the `parents` field.

My expectation is to retrieve all commits from the API in the order like what are presented in the webpage, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You have merges, don't you? There _is_ no order, presuming that's so.

Comment: Let's say you have a diamond: A has children B and C, both of which are merged into D. Whether B or C is shown first is arbitrary -- one could look at the timestamps in the header of the commit and decide based on that, and it would be a reasonable decision; or you could put them in the order of the parent header in D, and that would be a reasonable decision too. Nothing at all makes one way more right than the other, because they never both existed in the same tree until D happened; the tree having both as parents was synthesized at that one moment and never existed until then.

Comment: If you want to implement a binary search that's merge-aware, one already exists -- it's `git bisect`. The easy thing is to use that. The slightly less easy thing is to read its spec and implementation, and incorporate the workarounds its authors have already implemented.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry but I cannot make sure of that, given I am only to analyze it but not the author of it.From the webpage I get no sign that there happened a merge. But given the API reports different `parents`, I agree with there happened something.

Comment: you should see a single commit having _multiple_ parents, if there is in fact a merge

Comment: (oh! You provided actual links to a public repo! I feel silly for not looking already).

Comment: for a better description of what I was trying to say above, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect-lk2009#_git_bisect_details

Comment: not a merge commit; 8659c6991adb9e2f83a8f3af6bd90321adfe8f68 has exactly one parent, and that parent is dedcf74c2fb61a9ff7f1a1529f32dbca999cb678. Don't look at the UI (which I'm guessing is sorting by date?), look at the parent fields in the headers (which tells you which commit is made on top of which other commit(s) and doesn't care if computers had their clocks set wrong). But **really**, if you're trying to implement bisection for git trees, read that document above; you can trivially get outright wrong results if you don't understand the data structure you're trying to find something in.

Comment: BTW, why do you think the API is telling you the parent is f2ed40aa? The API definitely agrees with the UI on this; it's showing dedcf74 as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so if I update my algorithm to lookup contents in `parents` field and  alter `8659c69`'s previous from `f2ed40a` to `dedcf74`, then the order would be the same as what in webpage (at least for this scenario, but I don't know if there still have more complicated), how about `f2ed40a`? I understand there may exist the problem to flatten a tree, but what I want is just simply  an order in GitHub's webpages 

Comment: What do you mean "how about f2ed40a"? It's not a parent, so it's not the prior thing. git _is_ a tree. Flattening a tree is what git-viewing software does, GitHub included. Would need to read their docs to see exactly what algorithm they use, if they even document it at all; might be proprietary and subject-to-change. If someone gave me a requirement to duplicate their UI I'd refuse / push back / explain why it's a bad design. (Granted, I'm in a startup these days; nobody's more than two steps below C-level, so pushing back is easy)

Comment: Anyhow, as I discussed before, if your actual use case involves bisection -- you can't do that safely on a flat list; you'll get incorrect results in corner cases unless your bisection algorithm _knows_ that the actual data structure is a tree; the docs I linked you above describe this.

Comment: (and `git bisect` already does the work! it'd be a one liner to have it find the refactor for you -- since you can pass it a shell command to run to test each tree -- and then we'd be done)